# How to execute --track, using GitPython(as a python script). "git checkout -B <branchname> --track origin/<TeamBranch>"

Tags: python-3.x, git-checkout, gitpython

I can execute "git checkout -B  --track origin/TeamBranch" through terminal. but I have the requirement to implement the above command through my script using Gitpython.
can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly)

```
git = repo.git
git.checkout('HEAD', b="TeamBranch")
```